# Having Trouble Switching Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I'm just learning some java.  I am currently learning if, else statements.

In the game I am creating, the user picks a number between 0 and 10 and puts it into an input box.  If correct, the image on screen changes to one picture, if incorrect, it switches to a different picture.  However, I cannot seem to get the images to change at all.  I've tried a few different ways of coding; I'm currently using an img array.  However, when I do the code I receive an ObjectHTMLImageElement error.

Here is my current code:

```
<div id="top">
    <h1>Pie in the Face</h1>
    <p>Guess how many fingers I'm holding up between 0 and 10.
        <br /> If you guess correctly, I get a pie in the face.
        <br /> If you guess wrong, you get a pie in the face.</p>

    <input id="answer" />
    <button id="myButton">Submit</button>
    </center>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="manpie"></div>
    <div id="girlpie"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = Math.random();

    x = 11 * x;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    var imgArray = new Array();

    imgArray[0] = new Image();
    imgArray[0].src = "images/manpie2.jpg";

    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    imgArray[1].src = "images/girlpie2.jpg";


    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {

        if (x == document.getElementById("answer").value) {
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = imgArray[0];

            // what I had document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=imgArray[0];

        } else {
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = imgArray[1];
        }

    }
</script>

</body>
```

I have also tried using lines such as: `document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=document.getElementById("manpie");`

and then nothing works.  Here is a link to the "live" site it's on.
http://176.32.230.6/mejorarcr.com/

any help would be appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: First of all there is a big difference between [tag:java] and [tag:javascript]. Indeed, Java is a thing and JavaScript is another thing, but both are programming languages.

Comment: hmmm okay, I guess I need to learn that difference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the `innerHTML` value in your code:

```
if (x==document.getElementById("answer").value) {
          document.getElementById("image").innerHTML='<img src="'+imgArray[0].src+'" />';

          // what I had document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=imgArray[0].src;

         } else {
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML='<img src="'+imgArray[1].src+'" />';
         }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/rihoqo/1/) or [**this**](http://jsbin.com/rihoqo/2/)

Comment: Nice demo ... I could play that all night. :D

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!  I'm entirely certain why I would have to change the image source there if I referenced the array, but perhaps it's just one of those things that just are..like in math, some things just are.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=imgArray[0];
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", imgArray[0]);
```

make sure imgArray[0] is the actual image path:

```
          imgArray[0]="images/manpie2.jpg";

          imgArray[1]="images/girlpie2.jpg";
```

Comment: Thank you!  That makes some sense, it all still baffles me a little, but that helps with some thought patterns I have to get locked in.